# Google Maps local not working constantly

Tags: javascript, html, maps

I am trying to implement Google maps with a specified location on an website. Trying it for the first time, got the code from google dev and it doesn't work how it should, let me explain:

It works sometimes( when I load the page sometimes, or click in and out of other links, but not constantly) and no error on the log. I haven't noticed a pattern so that's why I am posting here. Really appreciate you reading this and giving your input!

**First the HTML:**

```
   <h2>My Google Maps Demo</h2>
   <div id="map"></div>

    <script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDwCEHnAjByWbixBh7zEm0VT712Cmlc(not the real key)callback=initMap">
    </script>
    <script src="javascript/scripts.js"></script>
```

**Second the JS**:

```
function initMap() {
var uluru = {lat: 46.77889, lng: 23.58624};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 16,
          center: uluru
        });
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: uluru,
          map: map
        });
  }
```

Comment: Have you read all the instructions? -- https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/google_maps_basic.asp

Comment: Truth be told, I tried the google developer instructions. I will try it with W3 and come back with a conclusion. Thanks for your response!

Comment: Here you have an example, check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/teutakoraqi/n64324pn/27/